# match array of posted values to an array of functions in php

Tags: php, arrays, forms, post, checkbox

I have a basic logic questions. My goal is to take the selected checkboxes from a form, submit them as an array and then match the values to an array of functions. Im trying to find a way of matching the selected input with the array of functions so i don't end up with pages of if {} elseif{} statements to cover an ever increasing number of options.

Here is an example of how i have my webform setup that contains a group of checkboxes. I am using "[]" to pass the selected values as an array.

webform:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="action[]" value="open" checked>open</input>
<input type="checkbox" name="action[]" value="close">close</input>
<input type="checkbox" name="action[]" value="lift">lift</input>
<input type="checkbox" name="action[]" value="drop">drop</input>
<input type="checkbox" name="action[]" value="destroy">destroy</input>
<input type="checkbox" name="action[]" value="create">create</input>
```

php post handler

```
$o = open();
$c = create();
$l = lift();
$d = drop();
$de = destroy();
$cr = create();

$mysvcs = array($o, $c, $l, $d, $de, $cr);


//stuck here
$action = $_POST['action'];
$postsvc = implode(",", $action );  

$req = strstr($mysvcs, $postsvc);

?>
```

I sense that i'm probably going about this in completely the wrong way and would appreciate any guidance from the community.

Many thanks

-AussiedeviL

Comment: What is it you plan to with the input? You want to verify that each value received is one of your acceptable parameters?  For that you should use `in_array()` - loop over `$_POST['action']` and verify that each action is `in_array()` of you array of accepted actions, which are just strings like `array('open','close','lift','drop'...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to execute the checked functions the following code should work :

```
function open() {} //your open declaration 
function close() {} //your close declaration 
function lift() {} //your lift declaration 
//all other declarations

foreach($_POST['action'] as $a){
    $a();//execute matching function 
}
```

Comment: worked perfectly, kicking myself for not thinking about that:). Many thanks!